How to automatically print a ggplot after creating it?
I would like to find a way to create my graph and print it in one command run, so I don't have to move my cursor back and forth everytime I make a small change in my plot. Here is an example.
  data <- data.frame(
  x = runif(5),
  y = runif(5)
)

graph <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()

print(graph)

Right now, I'm running my graph in two steps : one press of Ctrl+Enter to create the plot, another Ctrl+Enter to print it.
I've tried to work with pipe operators and the + sign but neither of them work :
Plus sign :
graph <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  print(graph)

Output :
Error in `ggplot_add()`:
! Can't add `print(graph)` to a <ggplot> object.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Pipe operator :
graph <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() %>% 
  print()

Output :
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity 

So here I just get a commande output but no graph printed.
What would be the solution ?

You can wrap in (), i.e. (graph <- ggplot() + ...).

library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  x = runif(5),
  y = runif(5)
)

(graph <- data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point())


Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.1.0
